# Access site from local network. It sends requests to localhost server, but the server is on the machine, that serves the site

Tags: node.js, reactjs, localhost

I am creating app. I build it with nodejs on server. It consists of several servers. My fronted sends requests to servers on localhost to fetch data from local servers ( so the urls for fetching data on the client is like localhost:3000/fetch_some). But when i want to visit the site from other computer of the local network ( i write in browser the ip of computer with fronted and servers, like `192.168.0.4:frontend_app_port`), the front side trying to fetch data from localhost of the computer i am running on, and it will not work, because there are no servers, that serves data on it. How to deal with it? Always configure front to send requests to `192.168.0.4`/(detect the computer local network ip) .
 Or there are some good issues for it? Does docker will be the right fit for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the server's name or address, you can't reach the back end by referring to localhost from your front-end code.

Comment: Dear, what do you mean with `server's name` ? How to achieve this?

Comment: if your server is 192.168.0.4:port then you need to replace "localhost" in your UI code to say "192.168.0.4:port"